# Default value for the preference in the android application is not updating

Tags: android

In my preference xml I have:

```
<EditTextPreference
        android:title="Location"
        android:key="@string/pref_location_key"
        android:defaultValue="689558"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:singleLine="true" />
```

So the default value for this preference supposed to be "689558", but when I run my app it looks like this:

[image]

In short, I have mysterious "94043" value instead of "689558". 
Where I could make mistake?

Comment: I've made recursive search for "94043" in my project files but found nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Didn't you set your preference before? Try to delete the app data from settings/applications and reinstall your app. 
If you set the preference once it will remain the same independently from restart or reinstall.

Comment: Thank you very much, I've cleared my data, then it works fine. I thought that when I reinstall app my data clears automaticly, but it's not like this, that was the problem